# compiler warning: left shift of negative value

Tags: c, gcc, gcc-warning

I think GCC is wrongfully producing a [-Wshift-negative-value] warning.

I have a function that should produce a suffix mask of a certain length provided by its single input argument:

```
#include <stdint.h>

uint16_t get_suffix_mask_sht(uint8_t shift) {
    return (~(~((uint16_t) 0) << shift));
}
```

I have tried to compile this function with the following compiler options on different versions of gcc

```
-Werror -Wextra
```

This warning also occurs if I change the output from `uint16_t` to `uint8_t`. Bigger output types, i.e. `uint32_t` don't produce this warning.

I am using an older version of GCC: 7.4. But I have tried this out on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/) using the latest GCC 9.x versions and they all produce the same warning. Clang versions however do not produce this error.

Comment: Just a little note: why do you use a prototype, if the definition follows just in the line below?

Comment: Oh it was just a remnant of my compiler complaining about missing declaration. I'll remove it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Warning is correct.

`~((uint16_t) 0)` results in negative value, because result of `(uint16_t) 0` is promoted to `int` before bitwise complement is performed.

In general you should prefer unsigned integers (wide enough to avoid type promotion) when using bit shifting. My suggestion would be to use `unsigned int` zero instead:

```
return (~(~0U << shift));
```

Comment: Ah thanks for the quick answers! So instead of `~((uint16_t) 0)` I should use `uint16_t (-1)`?

Comment: @ArisKoning Won't work as integer promotion will also be done to both operands of the bitwise shift operators.

Comment: Ok, well at least I now understand that the problem is with rules of integer promotion. I'll see if I can rewrite this somehow.

Answer (score 6):

When variables smaller than `int` (like e.g. `uint16_t`) are used with the bitwise complement operator `~` they are [promoted to `int`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Integer_promotions).

The type `int` is signed, and will not work well with shifting. Especially considering that `~0` will be `-1` with two's complement notation (which is the most common notation for representing negative numbers on binary systems).

A possible solution is to use larger unsigned types (like `unsigned int`) and then use masking to get the relevant bits for the smaller type when done.